# Zend Framework: view baseUrl() returns an empty string, while the controler's getRequest()->getBaseUrl() works fine

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller, view-helpers

I'm using Zend Framework for an MVC application.

When I need the base Url in the view, it always returns `""` (empty string); In my controllers, if I use `$this->getRequest()->getBaseUrl()`, it returns the correct base Url.

In example, I use the development application environment through `index.dev.php` (production is `index.php`); In production, I expect all my URLs to start with `""` as baseUrl, but in development environment, using index.dev.php, I expect all my URLs to start with `"/index.dev.php"`.

As I say before, the view's `baseUrl()` helper returns an empty string, even in development environment. But using `$this->getRequest()->getBaseUrl()` in the same environment, returns the correct base URL.

To solve this, I changed all my view's `$this->baseUrl()` calls to `$this->baseUrl`, and I defined this view variable in a custom base controller class. But this is not the solution I expect.

This is a modular application, and I am using routes, added in Bootstrap time like this:

```
protected function _initRoutes(){

    $objFrontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $objRouter = $objFrontController->getRouter();

    $arrAppRoutes = Service_Route::getAllActiveApplicationRoutes();

    if( is_array($arrAppRoutes) && count($arrAppRoutes) > 0 ){

        $objRouter->addRoutes($arrAppRoutes);

        // Add the default routes in the end
        $objRouter->addDefaultRoutes();
    }
}
```

These routes are all instance of `Zend_Controller_Router_Route` class, and when I use them in the view like this: `$this->url(array(), 'admin_dashboard');`, the `baseUrl` is correct always (even before using the `baseUrl` view var solution).

If someone knows about this, please help. If you need more info about my application setup, I'll provide it as much as I can.

**Edit**

Actually, there seems to be a problem: The empty string `baseUrl`, works fine including JS and CSS scripts in the view; But there are times where I need to use Ajax, and there the Base URL should have the `/index.dev.php` part, to keep the application environment. I don't know if this last part should be in the same question, or in a new question.

Comment: `Zend_View_Helper_BaseUrl` is actually a proxy to `Zend_Controller_Request_Http->getBaseUrl()` except it also removes the script name.

Answer (score 0):

Since baseUrl inside a view strips the script name, appending `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` should fix it.